# OnServiceConnected never executes

Tags: android

I'm getting the next exception, when I called a method in a Service, and when debug, I see that onServiceConnected never executes. I've tried to put Logs inside it, but it never executes, I get tired of waiting for it.

```
05-18 19:31:13.998    7031-7031/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.geochildfragment.app, PID: 7031
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.geochildfragment.app.ActivityMain.sendPin(ActivityMain.java:249)
        at com.geochildfragment.app.FragmentLinkDevice$4.onClick(FragmentLinkDevice.java:224)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4626)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19293)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my activity, I call the sendPin method, that it's throwing the exception, from a fragment:

```
int bStatus;
Boolean connected = false;
BluetoothDevice bDevice;
private BLEService bleService;
BluetoothGattService gattService;
public static final String EXTRA_BLUETOOTH_DEVICE = "BT_DEVICE";
BluetoothAdapter bAdapter;
Context context;


private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder service) {
        bleService = ((BLEService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
        if (!bleService.initialize()){
            finish();
        }
        bleService.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        bleService=null;
    }
};


private final BroadcastReceiver serviceUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BLEService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            connected = true;
            //invalidateOptionsMenu();
        } else if (BLEService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            connected = false;
            //invalidateOptionsMenu();
        } else if (BLEService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            List<BluetoothGattService> servicesList;
            servicesList = bleService.getSupportedGattServices();
            Iterator<BluetoothGattService> iter = servicesList.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                BluetoothGattService bService = (BluetoothGattService) iter.next();
                if (bService.getUuid().toString().equals(BLEUUID.SERVICE)){
                    gattService = bService;
                }
            }
        } else if (BLEService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
            ........

        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = getApplicationContext();

    Bundle extra = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    getConnectedDevices(extra);

    if (mServiceConnection == null){
        Log.v("NULL", "mServiceConnection NULL");
    }

    Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(this, BLEService.class);
    if (gattServiceIntent==null){
        Log.v("NULL", "mServiceConnection NULL");
    }
    bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    bStatus = BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unbindService(mServiceConnection);
    bleService = null;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(serviceUpdateReceiver, makeGattUpdateIntentFilter());
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(serviceUpdateReceiver);
}

private static IntentFilter makeGattUpdateIntentFilter() {
    final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(BLEService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED);
    intentFilter.addAction(BLEService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
    intentFilter.addAction(BLEService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
    intentFilter.addAction(BLEService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE);
    return intentFilter;
}

@Override
public void sendPin(BluetoothDevice bDevice, String pin) {
    String deviceAddress = bDevice.getAddress();
    bleService.connect(deviceAddress);
    bleService.sendPINCharacteristic(pin, bDevice);
}

public void verifyPIN(String data){
    FragmentLinkDevice f = (FragmentLinkDevice) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.link_device_fragment);
    if (data.contains(BroadcastIDs.OK)){
        f.launchDeviceConfigActivity()
    } else if (data.contains(BroadcastIDs.FAIL)){
        f.launchAlertDialog();
    }
}
```

}

In the manifest I've declared it by:

```
    <service android:name="Bluetooth.BLEService" android:enabled="true"/>
```

This is the service:

```
public class BLEService extends Service {

private static int DELAY = 3000;

private final static String TAG = BLEService.class.getSimpleName();
public Context context;
private BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private String mBluetoothDeviceAddress;
private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
private int mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
BluetoothGattService mService;
private static final int STATE_DISCONNECTED = 0;
private static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 1;
private static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 2;


public final static String ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED ="com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED";
public final static String ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED ="com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED";
public final static String ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED ="com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED";
public final static String ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE ="com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE";
public final static String EXTRA_DATA ="com.example.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA";


public final static String SERVICE = BLEUUID.SERVICE;
public final static UUID PIN_CHARACTERISTIC = UUID.fromString(BLEUUID.PIN_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID);
public final static UUID PUK_CHARACTERISTIC = UUID.fromString(BLEUUID.PUK_UUID);
public final static UUID INTERVAL_CHARACTERISTIC = UUID.fromString(BLEUUID.INTERVAL_UUID);
public final static UUID ROUTE_INTERVAL_CHARACTERISTIC = UUID.fromString(BLEUUID.ROUTE_INTERVAL_UUID);
public final static UUID ON_OFF_CHARACTERISTIC = UUID.fromString(BLEUUID.ON_OFF_UUID);
public final static UUID GPS1_CHARACTERISTIC= UUID.fromString(BLEUUID.GPS1_UUID);
public final static UUID GPS2_CHARACTERISTIC= UUID.fromString(BLEUUID.GPS2_UUID);
public final static UUID BATTERY_CHARACTERISTIC = UUID.fromString(BLEUUID.BATTERY_LEVEL_UUID);
public final static UUID DEVICE_NAME_CHARACTERISTIC = UUID.fromString(BLEUUID.DEVICE_NAME_UUID);
```

private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {

```
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        String intentAction;
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
            mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
            broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
            // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
            Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                    mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());

        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
            mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
            Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
            broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            Devices device = new Devices();
            device = device.FindByDeviceAddress(mBluetoothDeviceAddress);
            //showPerimeterNotification(device);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            for (BluetoothGattService service : gatt.getServices()) {
                if ((service == null) || (service.getUuid() == null)) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (BLEUUID.SERVICE.equalsIgnoreCase(service.getUuid().toString())) {
                    mService = service;
                }
            }
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {                
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
            broadcastUpdate(EXTRA_DATA, characteristic);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        readCharacteristic(characteristic);
        broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status){
        if (status== BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS){
            Toast.makeText(context, "onDescriptorWrite: SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "onDescriptorWrite: FAILURE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};

private void broadcastUpdate(final String action) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
private void broadcastUpdate(final String action,final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);

    if (PIN_CHARACTERISTIC.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
        final String pin = characteristic.getStringValue(0);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, BroadcastIDs.PIN + String.valueOf(pin));
        disconnect();

    }
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public BLEService getService() {
        return BLEService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    close();
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

public boolean initialize() {
    if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
        mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean connect(final String address) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
        return false;
    }

    // Previously connected device.  Try to reconnect.
    if (mBluetoothDeviceAddress != null && address.equals(mBluetoothDeviceAddress)
            && mBluetoothGatt != null) {
        if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
            mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    if (device == null) {
        return false;
    }

    mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
    mBluetoothDeviceAddress = address;
    mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
    return true;
}

public void disconnect() {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
}

public void close() {
    if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.close();
    mBluetoothGatt = null;

}

public void readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
    Log.i("READ", "CARACTERISTICA LEIDA");
}

public void setCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, boolean enabled) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);
    if (PIN_CHARACTERISTIC.equals(characteristic.getUuid())){
        /*BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor
                (UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(BLEUUID.fromHexToString(BLEUUID.PIN_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG_DESCRIPTOR)));*/
        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor =
                new BluetoothGattDescriptor(UUID.fromString(BLEUUID.CONFIG_UUID),BluetoothGattDescriptor.PERMISSION_WRITE_SIGNED);

        //descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);
        mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
    }
}

public List<BluetoothGattService> getSupportedGattServices() {
    if (mBluetoothGatt == null) return null;
    return mBluetoothGatt.getServices();
}


public void sendPINCharacteristic(String pin, BluetoothDevice device){

    byte[] pinByte = pin.getBytes();
    int pinInt = Integer.valueOf(pin);

    connect(device.getAddress());

    final BluetoothGattCharacteristic ch = (BluetoothGattCharacteristic) mService.getCharacteristic(UUID
            .fromString(BLEUUID.PIN_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID));

    ch.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
    ch.setValue(pin);

    mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
    setCharacteristicNotification(ch, true);
    mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(ch);        
}
```

}

Does somebody know what's the problem?

Comment: What line of code is `ActivityMain.java:249`?

Comment: That line contains:          bleService.connect(deviceAddress);

Comment: It's likely that `b` is null in that case. Have you initialized it?

Comment: Sorry, that line contains bleService.connect(deviceAddress)

Comment: It's likely that `bleService` is null in that case. Where is your `BLEService` class that extends `Service`?

Comment: I`ve added Service code

Answer (score 1):

Try to declare the complete package path for the BLEService class in your AndroidManifest.xml. For example

`<service android:name="com.example.bluetooth.le.BLEService" android:enabled="true"/>`